# crosstalk package error in datatable

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio, dt

When attempting to render a html app with  crosstalk between leaflet/DT, I get the following error:

```
Error in datatable(sd, extensions = "Scroller", style = "bootstrap", class = "compact",  : 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
```

data frame:

```
df2 <-   data.frame(
    structure(list(lat = c(-20.42, -20.62, -26, -17.97, -20.42, -19.68, 
    -11.7, -28.11, -28.74, -17.47, -21.44, -12.26, -18.54, -21, -20.7, 
    -15.94, -13.64, -17.83, -23.5, -22.63), long = c(181.62, 181.03, 
    184.1, 181.66, 181.96, 184.31, 166.1, 181.93, 181.74, 179.59, 
    180.69, 167, 182.11, 181.66, 169.92, 184.95, 165.96, 181.5, 179.78, 
    180.31), depth = c(562L, 650L, 42L, 626L, 649L, 195L, 82L, 194L, 
    211L, 622L, 583L, 249L, 554L, 600L, 139L, 306L, 50L, 590L, 570L, 
    598L), mag = c(4.8, 4.2, 5.4, 4.1, 4, 4, 4.8, 4.4, 4.7, 4.3, 
    4.4, 4.6, 4.4, 4.4, 6.1, 4.3, 6, 4.5, 4.4, 4.4), stations = c(41L, 
    15L, 43L, 19L, 11L, 12L, 43L, 15L, 35L, 19L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 10L, 
    94L, 11L, 83L, 21L, 13L, 18L)), .Names = c("lat", "long", "depth", 
    "mag", "stations"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
        )
```

Reproducible code:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)     #devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet', force = TRUE)
library(DT)

# Wrap data frame in SharedData
sd <- SharedData$new(quakes[sample(nrow(quakes), 10),])

# Create a filter input
filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1, width=250)

# Use SharedData like a dataframe with Crosstalk-enabled widgets
bscols(
        leaflet(sd) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(),
        datatable(sd, extensions="Scroller", style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",
                  options=list(deferRender=TRUE, scrollY=300, scroller=FALSE))
          )
```

And the platform and pkg versions:
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
crosstalk_1.0.1   (#installed from devtools/github)
leaflet_1.0.2.9010
DT_0.2

Answer (score 9):

install 'DT' from devtool/github.

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```